# Windows 7 SP1 SMB (Port 135/445) enabled by default upon install?

Tags: windows-7, server-message-block, exploit

I'm curious as over several years ever since I started researching about computer security, SMB has been a place where remote code execution happens the most on the windows OS. Especially With the recent vulnerability MS17-010 Eternal blue. Therefore I am wondering if the Windows 7 SP1 installer has port 135 and port 445 opened by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're closed on the default install of the original ISOs. It will open up as soon as you start sharing a printer or a folder.
But consider that there are a lot of custom Windows around, and I think it's possible that some customizer enables files and print sharing (to make a public shared folder on their default install, for instance).

Comment: By the way is there a way a regular User trigger this ?

Comment: You will have to research and experiment if you want to learn hacking, not asking on forums! ;)

Comment: No i'am asking if a regular everyday user can trigger this by doing normal stuff on there computer such as printing and what not